What does it mean to have fractional degrees of freedom
I have the following question:

The specific heats, Cp and Cy of a gas of diatomic molecules, A, are given (in units of J mol-1 K-¹) by 29 and 22, respectively. Another gas of diatomic molecules, B, has the corresponding values 30 and 21. If they are treated as ideal gases, then:

Options:

(1) A has one vibrational mode and B has two


(2) Both A and B have a vibrational mode each


(3) A is rigid but B has a vibrational mode


(4) A has a vibrational mode but B has none

Doing the calculations I get degrees of freedom of A about 6.28 and that of B about 4.6.
Now what does it mean to have fractional degrees of freedom to an ideal gas.
The calculations are:
Ratio of specific heats, $\gamma = \frac{C_p}{C_v} = 1 + \frac{2}{f}$. This is because $C_v = fR/2$ and $C_p = C_v + R$. Where $f$ is degrees of freedom and $R$ is ideal gas constant. Solving for $f$ for gases A and B, we get the values as written above.
The answer is option (4),because expected d.o.f for a diatomic gas is 5, and one of them has d.o.f less than 5, the other has more than 5. Thus one must have a vibrational mode of freedom, typically at high temperatures. However, I wish to understand what it means to have fractional d.o.f

It looks like they assume R = 9 J/K/mol. // Be aware that for vibration, the contribution is fR and not fR/2, as it includes both kinetic and potential energy. Additionally, vibration modes are discriminated at low t due high quantization steps. Consider the context of the task, if they assume quntum effects or not.

The question you quote  is  very curious. All diatomic molecules must have one vibration, making 2 the only correct answer no matter what the numbers quoted are. The classical thermodynamic values for the heat capacity you use only apply at v high temperature when all motions are fully populated. You need to consult statistical mechanics and partition functions to calculate values at lower temperatures. $C_V$, for example, is the gradient of internal energy with temperature so you can appreciate why $C_V$ increases as temperature increases, and this is why $f$ values are fractions.

Fractional DOFs means that some energy modes (vibration, rotation), related to a particular degree of freedom, are discriminated by energy quantization effects (small quantization steps for rotation, bigger for vibration) .
The gas with $\ce{\text{DOF} \lt 5}$ is $\ce{H2}$, as it is  as the lightest diatomic gas the only one with rotation DOFs still partly discriminated at room temperature, not yet fully participating in the energy distribution yet.
The gas with $\ce{\text{DOF} \gt 5}$ is some gas with higher molar mass, as vibration modes start to kick in for the heavy molecules first. For most of light diatomic gases, vibration kicks in above $70-\pu{100 ^\circ C}$.
Wikipedia - Molar_heat_capacity:

